# how to loading 8000 port in android webview

Tags: android, webview, raspberry-pi, port

Good morning.RE Load a web page from `raspberry pi` through the Android web page.

Raspberry IP refers to 172.20.10.10 or 172.20.10.10: 80.

The web page of the `Apache server` has been loaded.

You can not access web pages with 8000 port.

Raspberry writes 8000 ports on `webiopi`. So I'm trying to connect the 8000 port to the app. If i type 172.20.10.10:8000 on the web, i can load the web page well. However, if i enter 172.20.10.10:8000 as `url` with the Android `webview`, i can not call it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Port 80 is the default web server "listen" port. You can change it, why would you want too ? 172.20.10.10 is the "same" as 172.20.10.10: 80 because it is the default. It is ubiquitous that web servers use port 80 to listen on non-secure (http) requests. Port 8080 was often chosen as a convenient place to host a secondary or alternate web server. https port 443 by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
What I was wondering. On the web, 8000 port or 80 port all work well. Why does the app fail to load pages when using 8000 ports, and what is the solution.

Comment: On the web port 8000 does NOT work well (try: http://www.google.co.uk:8000/ {it  does NOT work}). There is no solution, because there is no problem ! It does not work on port 3763 nor 8734 nor an infinite number of other random numbers. Why is port 8000 so important to you ? Update your question, it makes no sense in it's present form.

Comment: I know port 8000 is Commonly used for internet radio streams such as those using SHOUTcast. Sometimes also used as an alternative HTTP port. See  https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8000

Comment: Raspberry writes 8000 ports on webiopi. So I'm trying to connect the 8000 port to the app. If i type http://172.20.10.10:8000 on the web, i can load the web page well. However, if i enter http://172.20.10.10:8000 as url with the Android webview, i can not call it.

Comment: Is it because using 8000 port on Android and i can not get web page because the port is overlapping?

Comment: It's only a guess but probably "on the web" the browser is hacking off the port number so it goes to the default (web browser's do that), but Android webview is taking you literally and failing (as it probably should). Look more closely at what is happening "on the web". I doubt raspberry  pi is REALLY listening on port 8000. Look in your Apache config file.

Comment: Does the browser change to the default value of 8000 even if i enter 8000 port? I think it is not. The 80 port has a different page than the 8000 port. On the web, 80 port pages and 8000 port pages are different pages, loading different pages well.

Comment: To be sure you need to show your config file from Apache. It will be something like C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf         and contain Listen 192.168.1.100:80     and MAYBE Listen 192.168.1.100:8000

Comment: Are you saying httpd.conf file? i will send it atfet work...

Comment: yes httpd.conf I know it's not windows but you get the point ? Edit out any secret stuff in there (for the security of your server). It should be o.k. to share.  ALSO show the logcat from Android when you fail to connect, the error code may be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :8080 or :8888 as you may need to use different port depending on your setup. Also confirm that apache is running on the Raspberry pie. Make sure you did the apt-get apache command and started it as well on the Raspberry pie before trying to hit it and make sure you are on the same network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
The Apache server is running fine. What I want is webiopi, a raspberry pie control site that is open on port 8000. The 80 port on the Apache server loads well on the Android webview, is there a reason why i can not call port 8000 called webiopi? On the Web, both port 8000 and port 80 work well.

Comment: Gotcha, did you already do the install properly and configurations to open the port and run it so that it is accessible? http://webiopi.trouch.com/INSTALL.html if so you can try killing apache to see if there is a conflict, but yes 80 is default.

Comment: Yes. I can install webiopi properly and use webiopi on the web. I am curious as to whether webiopi 8000 port can not be accessed, but port 80 can access web page.

Comment: This is an old question, but a genuine problem. FastApi/uvicorn defaults to port 8000 and, of course, low number ports require root (if only at beginning). I've switched my uvicorn server serving a FastApi Python script to 8080 and the app connects to do some REST transactions. Hope this helps someone else.